# Pushing to Heroku with Rails/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am trying to push to Heroku. I have postgres and have set the buildpacks for Heroku. However I believe it is my file structure that is causing the error.

Main-File -> ProjectName -> RubyProj ->(this is where all the ruby controllers gem stuff is)

Main-File is my git repo and I am trying to push just the RubyProj file to heroku Is there a good way to do this without doing another git init on the RubyProj file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is possible to push only your RubyProj file to heroku, but I don't understand which type of error are you encountering. Try to switch to the appropriate git branch and push the project from the terminal.

```
cd ~/ProjectName/RubyProj
git checkout master
git commit -m
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

Also check all the gems and correct bundle installation.
Maybe this book will help you. https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-deploying
Good luck, hope I helped you!

Comment: @tnaught Did my answer helped you?